# Does flutter default primary swatch to purple on material 3?

Tags: flutter

This is a flutter web project on Flutter 3.10.5.
I'm trying to change the border color on a textfield in flutter, and I noticed that the color is purple, even when I haven't declared purple any where in my theme or primary swatch. I easily solved the problem but I need to understand the source of this weird theming.

[image: code]

[image: weird behaviour]

So I added just one border color and it's purple, I added all the borders to fix the change, but I noticed even the cursor color is purple as well. and my primary swatch is grey.

Comment: Hi ! Did you find something ?

Comment: Hmm no replies. I am seeing this purple thing with buttons, backgrouds etc

Comment: Didn't find any reasons why. I guess it does default to purple on material 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is global definition of the border color and cursor color.

```
...
textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(cursorColor: Colors.grey), // <-- change color
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple)), // <-- change color
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple)), // <-- change color
  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)), // <-- change color
  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)), // <-- change color
  filled: true,
  fillColor: Colors.white),
...
```

Comment: Really, so this is the source of the weird purple colour. It's the global definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The color is coming from the [`colorScheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/colorScheme.html) property of `ThemeData`. Try changing it to blue and see the result:

```dart
ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
  // ...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

See Dhafin Rayhan's answer to this Stack Overflow question for a workaround:

[After upgrading to Flutter 3.16, the app bar, background color, button size, and spaces change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77537315/after-upgrading-to-flutter-3-16-the-app-bar-background-color-button-size-and)

Comment: I don't want to opt out of material 3, I just don't want purple hidden in niche areas after having a primarySwatch that's not purple in any way.

Comment: a link on the answer sent me to the Material 3 Guide where everything is in purple, 

Comment: @aolsan Sorry that turning Material 3 off globally doesn't work for you. Funny enough, I didn't find that solution until after I had already changed the color of many widgets in my app one-by-one.  I also noticed how the link pointed to the Material 3 Guide where everything is purple. Go figure.