# After upgrading to Flutter 3.16, the app bar, background color, button size, and spaces change

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme, flutter-upgrade, flutter-material

I upgraded my Flutter version to 3.16. When I run my app, I notice a lot of changes in the UI.

1. The app bar doesn't have shadows anymore. When I scroll, the app bar is now tinted with a color and shown without shadows.
2. The background of the body was previously white, but now it's a bit tinted with a color.
3. Buttons and spaces appear to be larger now.
4. Alert dialogs, time pickers, date pickers, and other material components look different now. They appear with a tinted light purple color (or the color from theme I'm using).

[image: Before and after upgrading to Flutter 3.16]

---

How do I get the same UI appearance as I had before the upgrade to Flutter 3.16?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is the result of using [Material 3](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/design/material), which is enabled by default since Flutter 3.16. It's one of the [breaking changes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes#released-in-flutter-316) from the [Flutter 3.16 update](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes/release-notes-3.16.0).

You can opt out of Material 3 by specifying `useMaterial3: false` in your `ThemeData`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  // ...
  theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: false,
    // ...
  ),
)
```

Do take note that this [`useMaterial3`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/useMaterial3.html) flag is a temporary solution to give you time to migrate to Material 3. Eventually, only Material 3 will be supported.

---

To see the differences between Material 2 and Material 3, go to this interactive demo:
https://flutter.github.io/samples/web/material_3_demo/#/

To see all the breaking changes in the Flutter 3.16 update, go to this link:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes#released-in-flutter-316

Comment: Adding useMaterial3: false does not change anything, app still has material3 design instead of previous design.

Comment: You might need to perform a "hot restart" after changing that line @Elmar

Comment: Tried everything, not a newbie. Nothing helped, correcting all the affected widgets one by one now. If any UI element does not have explicitly defined colors, all of them turned into ugly pale colors. If I downgrade Flutter version, all design issues disappear.

Comment: This `useMaterial3` method should be enough, you surely messing with something else in your code. Consider making a question on its own so you can explain your problem in more detailed @Elmar

Comment: Agreed - I had the exact same issue as the OP, set the `useMaterial3` bool to false and bingo!

Comment: @Elmar Have you fixed your problem?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I have found that some pages have their own MaterialApp in addition to the one in the main.dart. So you need to make sure that there is only one high level MaterialApp or you need to set theme values to each of them one by one.

Comment: @Elmar Of course that would cause the issue. It is very unlikely that multiple `MaterialApp` is needed in a single app anyway. If you need to customize theme for particular widget you can use the `Theme` widget.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Material 3 is enabled by default since Flutter 3.16. So, to fix it, you can disable Material 3 as shown below or you can change the default value in your AppTheme like this:

```
ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      bottomSheetTheme: defaultTheme.bottomSheetTheme.copyWith(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
```

This example is for the BottomSheet, but you can do it for all your widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Material3 has a very good slide behaveior for `LisView` I needed to have them.
I did override all default material3 theme styles and colors as below.

```
import 'package:customer/screens/order/locations.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:customer/screens/pages/loading.dart';
import 'package:customer/shared/services/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Routes extends StatelessWidget {
  const Routes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
      systemNavigationBarColor:
          Colors.white, // Background color of the bottom status bar
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness:
          Brightness.dark, // Icon color of the bottom status bar
    ));
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) => MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
          child: child!),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: customTheme,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => Loading(),
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => Home(),
        '/location': (BuildContext context) => Locations(),
      },
    );
  }
}

ThemeData customTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: swatchify(),
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    foregroundColor: Tingsapp.fontColor,
    backgroundColor: Tingsapp.white,
    surfaceTintColor: Tingsapp.white,
  ),
  fontFamily: 'Outfit',
  textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
    cursorColor: Tingsapp.primary,
    selectionColor: Tingsapp.primary,
  ),
  elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
        RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Tingsapp.primary))),
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
          return Tingsapp.inActive;
        } else if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
          return Tingsapp.inActive;
        } else {
          return Tingsapp.primary; // Your primary color
        }
      },
    ),
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Tingsapp.black),
  )),
  textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
            return Tingsapp.inActive;
          } else if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
            return Tingsapp.inActive;
          } else {
            return Tingsapp.white; // Your primary color
          }
        },
      ),
      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Tingsapp.primary),
    ),
  ),
  outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Tingsapp.primary))),
          side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
              return BorderSide(color: Tingsapp.primary, width: 2);
            } else {
              return BorderSide(color: Tingsapp.primary, width: 2);
            }
          }),
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                return Tingsapp.primary;
              } else if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                return Tingsapp.primary;
              } else {
                return Tingsapp.white; // Your primary color
              }
            },
          ),
          foregroundColor:
              MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
              return Tingsapp.black;
            } else {
              return Tingsapp.primary;
            }
          }))),
  floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
    foregroundColor: Tingsapp.black,
    backgroundColor: Tingsapp.primary,
  ),
  inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Tingsapp.fontColor),
    focusColor: Tingsapp.primary,
    hoverColor: Tingsapp.primary,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Tingsapp.fontColor, width: 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Tingsapp.fontColor,
      ),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Tingsapp.fontColor,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  indicatorColor: Tingsapp.primary,
  focusColor: Tingsapp.primary,
  dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
  canvasColor: Colors.white,
  bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(backgroundColor: Tingsapp.white),
  dialogTheme: DialogTheme(backgroundColor: Tingsapp.white),
  dropdownMenuTheme: DropdownMenuThemeData(
    menuStyle:
        MenuStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Tingsapp.bgColor)),
  ),
);
```