# How can I change the overlay color of my flutter bottom navigation bar in flutter 3.16?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I recently upgraded my flutter SDK to version 3.16, and whenever I tap on my bottom navigation bar item icon, it produces a black overlay color in light theme mode. This kind of looks annoying and I want to change it. Please any idea on how to go about it?

I tried changing the overlay color but noticed the Bottom Navigation bar has no overlay property

[Link to Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ1NS.png)

Comment: This only happened after upgrading to Flutter 3.16 right? So maybe you want to opt out of Material 3 completely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77537316/13625293

Comment: Thanks for the help @Dhafin Rayhan, but I really do like the look and feel of the new material 3. isn't there another way to solve the issue?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the issue? Also if you like M3, you might want to check the M3 version of the navbar (which is different from BottomNavigationBar): [NavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar-class.html)

Comment: OK thank you. I've added a link to the screenshot. I am not permitted to add a proper screenshot since this is my first question post   https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ1NS.png

Comment: Thank you very much, i think the NavigationBar will be the best option