# Android studio not displaying default colour

Tags: flutter

I am working with flutter in android studio I use material app them for my primary colour for some reason when I change the colour it doesn’t update on the app and all of my appbars are now white

I have uninstalled android studio reset my Mac back to factory settings and downloaded my app from git where I know the colour was working and it’s still the same

Comment: Does this solution solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77537315/after-upgrading-to-flutter-3-16-the-app-bar-background-color-button-size-and/77537316#77537316