# Elevation property not working on flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add a shadow to the app bar in flutter and I'm getting build on android device but the elevation property is not working, the shadow is not visible

```
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(130.0),
        child: ClipPath(
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            toolbarHeight: 130.0, // Adjust the height as needed
            title: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: RichText(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "Biruni University\n",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "Attendance System",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post the image you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @BerkayÇatak  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnCAD.jpg

Comment: Perhaps you're using Material 3? The app bar in M3 doesn't have elevation. My suggestion is to stick with the nature of its design, but if you really want elevation, you can go back to Material 2: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77537315/13625293

Answer (score 0):

Try using box shadow. wrap appbar with container.

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
   boxShadow: [
     BoxShadow(
       color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
       spreadRadius: 5,
       blurRadius: 5,
       offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
     ),
   ],
 ),
 child: AppBar(
```