# ListView ThemeData after Flutter update

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, themedata

After the Flutter upgrade to Flutter Version 3.17, many controls have a new look. I managed to make most of the adjustments to get the old design back.
But I have a ListView in a Tab of a TabBar. The elements are now displayed a little differently. But I can't figure out where and how I have to make the necessary settings on the theme to get the old status back.
I'm missing the "shadow" between Tabbar and ListView.
I once took a greatly enlarged picture. Look for the new one on the left. On the right the old condition.
Can someone maybe give me a tip? Or is there a documentation on how to adapt the old Flutter ThemeData to the new ThemeData?

[image: left new/ right old design]

Comment: most likely https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/useMaterial3.html, more here: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/material-3-default

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After upgrading to Flutter 3.16, the app bar, background color, button size, and spaces change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77537315/after-upgrading-to-flutter-3-16-the-app-bar-background-color-button-size-and)