# Flutter UI issue...A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, overflow, pixel

I am developing a UI for my application using Flutter, and I finished it five days ago. Later, I started working on another application's UI. Now, when I suddenly opened my previous application, I encountered this error: "A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels on the right." Simultaneously, the Tab Bar I used in my application is fine to the left. However, today, when I opened it again, the Tab Bar shifted somewhat to the right, making my application look untidy. Another issue is that initially, when I was working, I used default icon colors, but now the colors of the icons have completely changed to black, making my application appear messy. Can anyone please help me resolve these problems?

I tried several alignments and paddings but nothing worked. Still my Tab bar is at same position

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your ThemeData may have been developed with material2 before, now material3 comes as default. You can check it by setting 'useMaterial3:false' in ThemeData.

Comment: If that's the case you can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77537315/13625293