# Change AppBar elevation color/mask with keeping elevation = 1

Tags: flutter, appbar, elevation

I have application that have one screen with `Drawer`. Main screen contains following `AppBar`:

```
AppBar(
   foregroundColor: Colors.white,
   backgroundColor: Colors.green,
   elevation: 0,      
   actions: // actions here
)
```

I want to keep the `AppBar` because of actions I have here. However, I do not want it to have any color. So I have added following code to the app `Scaffold`:

```
extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
```

It works well, now the `AppBar` is invisible, and the actions are visible. However, when I do something in the drawer and I close it, the AppBar starts to have strange color (not everytime). I have found out that it is still transparent, but something happened with the `elevation`, so it acts now like it has `elevation: 1.0`. Can somebody advise, how to solve this strange behavior? I think there might be problem with zero `elevation` for the both `AppBar` and the rest of the screen, and when `Drawer` comes above the screen and then closes, the equal elevations collide and therefore it sometimes changes `AppBar`. The best solution would be to be available to **remove any mask/additional effect that is made on `AppBar`**, when it have `elevation: 1`. Therefore, if I increase the elevation in `AppBar` and hide all effects, the `AppBar` would be truly transparent in any cases. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After upgrading to Flutter 3.16, the app bar, background color, button size, and spaces change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77537315/after-upgrading-to-flutter-3-16-the-app-bar-background-color-button-size-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "strange color" is actually `surfaceTintColor`, which makes the app bar tinted when using Material 3. To remove it, set it to transparent:

```
AppBar(
  // ...
  surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
),
```

To enable elevation shadow as it was in Material 2, see this post:

[After upgrading to Flutter 3.16, the app bar, background color, button size, and spaces change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77537315/13625293)

Answer (score 0):

App bar elevation and color change

```
 appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Custom Elevation Color'),
          elevation: 1, // Set elevation to 1
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue, // Set the background color of the AppBar
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white), // Set icon color
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), // Set text color
          ),
        ),
```

#flutter
#dart