# How can I make the app bar visible on the flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to create an app bar.

I created an app bar and set the color

I can't see the app bar

Did I set it up wrong? I wonder what the problem is.

This is my code. and simulator picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tphkM.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const RootPage(),
    );
  }
}

class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RootPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RootPage> createState() => _RootPageState();
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app bar is actually there, but in [Material 3](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/design/material) the color of the app bar by default blends with the background when it's not elevated. If you start placing widget on the title, for example, you can notice it being rendered:

```dart
AppBar(
  title: Text('My Screen'),
)
```

[image: Material 3 App Bar with Title Text]

Or you can put elevation to see the app bar starting to get tinted by the primary color:

```dart
AppBar(
  elevation: 2.0,
)
```

[image: Material 3 App Bar with Elevation]

If you were familiar with the way the app bar is rendered in Material 2, which has the theme primary color by default, you might be looking for this explanation:

[After upgrading to Flutter 3.16, the app bar, background color, button size, and spaces change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77537315/13625293)

If you decided to set `useMaterial3: false` in your `ThemeData`, the app bar will appear as the primary color even without having any further configurations set:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    // ...
    useMaterial3: false,
  ),
)
```

[image: Material 2 App Bar]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `Parameters` of `AppBar` like the below so that your app bar will appear's as you want.

```
AppBar(foregroundColor: Colors.red,
       title: const Text('Your Title'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `useMaterial3` to `false` in the **ThemData()** Widget within the **MaterialApp()** widget to observe the appbar displaying the primary color.

*Example Code :*

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: false,
    //rest of code...
  ),
);
```