# Flutter Appbar issues

Tags: android, flutter, appbar, scaffold

I am new to flutter. I used appBar property in Scaffold widget and although the color in the tutorial is default lightblue color, my appbar has no color.(typically white) And also I can't find any elevation property(The shadow in the appBar doesn't appear when I add colors to the appBar manually using backgroundColor property.) What are the possible issues and how to fix this? Something wrong with Material sdk?

I tried adding backgroundColor to the appBar, but it is not a correct way to solve this I think, because the shadow is not appearing in the appBar.(elevation: property doesn't worK)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make the app bar visible on the flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77945526/how-can-i-make-the-app-bar-visible-on-the-flutter)

Comment: Just give your code in the question so people can know what did you do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.