# Flutter: Card Widget - Why does elevation in Card Widget change the card's color?

Tags: flutter

I'm very new to this community and Flutter, also a non-native English person.
So, I'm doing the codelab of Material Structure and Layout from google (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-102-flutter#0).
While fiddling with the elevation property, I noticed that the background color of the Card changed.
I'm running the app on Android Emulator using a Windows laptop.
elevation: 1.
with elevation 1, the color hardly changed
[image]

elevation: 10.
with elevation 10, the color turn slightly pink with a shadow veil

[image]

My question is that why does this happen? Is there any way to avoid this? Do you suggest any other Widget that also has elevation without changing the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Flutter 3.16, Material 3 is enabled by default. In Material 3, giving elevation to a card will make the card tinted with its [`surfaceTintColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card/surfaceTintColor.html).

To elevate a card without having the tint color, you can set the `surfaceTintColor` property to `Colors.transparent`:

```dart
Card(
  surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
  // ...
)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`Card.filled`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card/Card.filled.html) constructor and set the color to white:

```dart
Card.filled(
  color: Colors.white,
  // ...
)
```

---

See also: [After upgrading to Flutter 3.16, the app bar, background color, button size, and spaces change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77537315/13625293)